# Can I trigger a program to run whenever a transaction occurs that isn't related to the program?

Tags: solana-program, program

Is it possible to write a Solana program that automatically interacts with the Solana chain whenever something happens?

A simple example would be: Whenever a dex such as Orca swaps USDC for SOL at a price of X, I want to also swap USDC for SOL. Basically the pseudocode is:

0 - Run program...

1 - Program continuously listens to Orca USDC-SOL pool...

2 - Program buys when last Orca price is below $X

Is it possible to have that program run? From [the docs](https://docs.solana.com/developing/on-chain-programs/deploying), it says that a client has to interact with a program in order for it to run... but can that interaction just be step 0? (Running the program)

Answer (score 1):

At the moment this is not possible natively. See [this proposal](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/17145).

However, you have some options:

- You could setup a server to listen to changes on an account you care about and then submit transactions yourself.
- You can also setup a validator and pipe out data from it using geyser. This would give you a firehouse of data that you can make decisions on.
- Another approach is to build a crank mechanism into your program and
  incentivize others to pull the crank. Lots of programs do this, you
  might even be able to build on top of one.
- Check out https://www.cronos.so/